# Count the repetition of an element in an array using a function with one parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

Good Day, I am trying to count how many times a particular element in an array appears. I tried but my code below counts only one of the array even if it appears more than once (this is not the problem). I want it to return the amount of time each element appears. For example

```
let arr = [1, 3, 2, 1];
```

this should return

```
{1:2} {3:1} {2:1}
```

My code returns 3 (as in it just doesn't count one twice)

How do i go about this?

Below is my code

```
function numberCount(number) {
    let count = 0;
    number.forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (number.indexOf(item) == index) count++;
    });
    console.log(count);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `filter` out these numbers, then use the `length`:

```js
let arr = [1, 3, 2, 1];

function itemCount(array) {
  var sorted = array.sort()
  var uniqueCount = sorted.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) == i);
  var count = [];
  uniqueCount.forEach(item => {
    var itemCount = sorted.filter(e => e == item).length;
    count.push({[item]: itemCount});
  });
  return count;
}

console.log(itemCount(arr));
```

Answer (score 3):

While iterating over `number` (better to call it `arr`, it's an array, not a number), use an object to keep track of the number of times each number has occured so far. Then, iterate over the resulting object's `entries` to create the objects desired:

```js
let arr = [1, 3, 2, 1];
function numberCount(arr) {
    let count = 0;
    const obj = arr.reduce((a, num) => {
      a[num] = (a[num] || 0) + 1;
      return a;
    }, {});
    return Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => ({ [key]: val }));
}
console.log(numberCount(arr));
```

Numeric keys always come in numeric order in an object. If you want the objects in the output to come in *insertion* order (eg, the object with key `3` before the object with key `2`), then use a `Map` instead of an object (map keys will be iterated over in insertion order):

```js
let arr = [1, 3, 2, 1];
function numberCount(arr) {
    let count = 0;
    const map = arr.reduce((a, num) => (
      a.set(num, (a.get(num) || 0) + 1)
    ), new Map());
    return [...map.entries()]
      .map(([key, val]) => ({ [key]: val }));
}
console.log(numberCount(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not reinventing the wheel, and instead use lodash which already has this function. Using [`countBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#countBy) you will get an object you can then convert into your desired result. For example:

```js
const arr = [1, 3, 2, 1]
const count = _.countBy(arr)
const result = Object.keys(count).map(k => ({ [k]: count[k] }))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```